# Add self-signed root ca to snap firefox from bash on Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: bash, firefox, snap

### Context

After looking at [various methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244582/add-certificate-authorities-system-wide-on-firefox?answertab=createdasc#tab-top) to add a self-signed, public root certificate (`ca.crt`) to (snap) Firefox, I experienced some difficulties.

### Other solutions

Firefox does not look at the system root ca's by default.

- However, [one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036637) answer found a hacky workaround to make it do that anyways.
- [Another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/369858) says the certificates first need to be imported by hand.
- And [the most recent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1360267), is from 2021, and suggest using the `policies.json`. That works for the apt version. However, for the snap version, the `policies.json` file is recognised (and used/imported) by Firefox, but the root ca named `ca.crt` is not added to the trusted root certificate authorities of snap Firefox (see "snap Firefox" section below for details).

### Question

How can one, reliably, and automatically, using Bash, add a root ca named `ca.crt` to a snap Firefox installation?

### Current Solution

The current solution adds the root ca to the apt (and snap) Firefox installation using the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Adds the root ca certificate named ca.crt to the apt or snap installation of Firefox.

add_self_signed_root_cert_to_firefox() {

  local policies_filepath
  policies_filepath=$(get_firefox_policies_path)

  local root_ca_filepath="$UBUNTU_CERTIFICATE_DIR$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME"

  if [ "$(file_exists "$policies_filepath")" == "FOUND" ]; then

    if [ "$(file_contains_string "$root_ca_filepath" "$policies_filepath")" == "NOTFOUND" ]; then

      # Create a backup of the existing policies.
      sudo rm backups/policies.json
      sudo cp "$policies_filepath" backups/policies.json

      # Generate content to put in policies.json.
      local new_json_content
      # shellcheck disable=SC2086
      new_json_content=$(jq '.policies.Certificates += {
                    "Install": ["'$root_ca_filepath'"]
               }' $policies_filepath)

      # Append the content
      echo "$new_json_content" | sudo tee "$policies_filepath" >/dev/null

    else
      red_msg "Your certificate is already added to Firefox."
      exit 6
    fi
  else
    new_json_content="$(create_policies_content_to_add_root_ca "$root_ca_filepath")"
    echo "$new_json_content" | sudo tee "$policies_filepath" >/dev/null
  fi

  # Assert the policy is in the file.
  if [ "$(file_contains_string "$root_ca_filepath" "$policies_filepath")" == "NOTFOUND" ]; then

    red_msg "Error, policy was not found in file:$policies_filepath" "true"
    exit 5
  fi

}

has_added_self_signed_root_ca_cert_to_firefox() {
  local policies_filepath
  policies_filepath=$(get_firefox_policies_path)

  local root_ca_filepath="$UBUNTU_CERTIFICATE_DIR$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME"
  read -p "root_ca_filepath=$root_ca_filepath"
  read -p "policies_filepath=$policies_filepath"

  # Assert the root project for this run/these services is created.
  if [ "$(file_exists "certificates/root/$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME")" != "FOUND" ]; then
    echo "NOTFOUND"
    return 0
  fi
  if [ "$(file_exists "$UBUNTU_CERTIFICATE_DIR$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME")" != "FOUND" ]; then
    echo "NOTFOUND"
    return 0
  fi
  # Assert the root ca hash is as expected.
  if [[ "$(md5sum_is_identical "$UBUNTU_CERTIFICATE_DIR$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME" "certificates/root/$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME")" != "FOUND" ]]; then
    echo "NOTFOUND"
    return 0
  fi

  if [ "$(file_exists "$policies_filepath")" == "FOUND" ]; then
    if [ "$(file_contains_string "$root_ca_filepath" "$policies_filepath")" == "NOTFOUND" ]; then
      echo "NOTFOUND"
      return 0
    elif [ "$(file_contains_string "$root_ca_filepath" "$policies_filepath")" == "FOUND" ]; then
      echo "FOUND"
      return 0
    fi
  else
    echo "NOTFOUND"
  fi
}

assert_has_added_self_signed_root_ca_cert_to_firefox() {
  if [[ "$(has_added_self_signed_root_ca_cert_to_firefox)" != "FOUND" ]]; then
    echo "Error, root ca certificate was not added to apt Firefox."
    exit 6
  fi
}

firefox_is_installed() {
  if [[ "$(firefox_is_installed_with_apt)" == "FOUND" ]]; then
    echo "FOUND"
  elif [[ "$(firefox_is_installed_with_snap)" == "FOUND" ]]; then
    echo "FOUND"
  else
    echo "NOTFOUND"
  fi
}

firefox_is_installed_with_apt() {
  if dpkg -l firefox &>/dev/null; then
    echo "FOUND"
  else
    echo "NOTFOUND"
  fi
}

firefox_is_installed_with_snap() {
  if snap list | grep -v firefox &>/dev/null; then
    echo "FOUND"
  else
    echo "NOTFOUND"
  fi
}

get_firefox_policies_path() {
  local policies_filepath

  #elif snap list | grep -v firefox &>/dev/null; then
  if [ "$(firefox_via_snap)" == "FOUND" ]; then
    # policies_filepath="/snap/firefox/current/distribution/policies.json"
    sudo mkdir -p "/etc/firefox/policies"
    policies_filepath="/etc/firefox/policies/policies.json"
  # TODO: prevent False positive on apt package if snap Firefox is installed.
  elif [[ "$(apt_package_is_installed "Firefox")" != "FOUND" ]]; then
    #if dpkg -l firefox &>/dev/null; then
    policies_filepath="/etc/firefox/policies/policies.json"
  else
    echo "Error, firefox installation was not found."
    exit 6
  fi
  echo "$policies_filepath"
}

create_policies_content_to_add_root_ca() {
  local root_ca_filepath="$1"
  local inner
  inner=$(
    jq -n --argjson Install '["'"$root_ca_filepath"'"]' \
      '$ARGS.named'
  )

  local medium
  medium=$(
    jq -n --argjson Certificates "$inner" \
      '$ARGS.named'
  )

  local final
  final=$(
    jq -n --argjson policies "$medium" \
      '$ARGS.named'
  )

  echo "$final"
  # Desired output (created with jq as exercise, and for modularity):
  # {
  # "policies": {
  # "Certificates": {
  #     "Install": [
  #                "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt"
  #                ]
  #          }
  #     }
  # }
}

close_restart_close_firefox() {
  # Close firefox.
  pkill firefox >>/dev/null 2>&1

  green_msg "Opening and closing Firefox, please wait 3 seconds." "true"
  # TODO: Verify no errors occur when running Firefox.
  # TODO: Verify Firefox was started successfully.
  nohup firefox >/dev/null 2>&1 &
  sleep 3

  pkill firefox >>/dev/null 2>&1
  green_msg "Proceeding with script." "true"
}
```

This works for the apt verion of Firefox. However, it does not work for the snap version of Firefox, details are in the next subsection.

### Snap Firefox Issue

For the standard installation on Ubuntu (snap Firefox), the content from the `/etc/firefox/policies/policies.json` is loaded. However, the certificate is not recognised. The link to the `ca.crt` is recognised:
[image]

However, it is not listed in the `about:preferences` > `certificates`:
[image]

On the apt version, the certificates are added and shown in that list.

### Note

For completeness, I also have a script to swap the snap installation to apt, however, I am looking for a less invasive method that preserves the Firefox settings of the user.

Answer (score 0):

By default snap uses **strict confinment**

[from the docs:](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement)

> Strict confinement uses security features of the Linux kernel,
> including AppArmor, seccomp and namespaces, to prevent applications
> and services accessing the wider system.

It means that by default firefox or whatever process running via files installed by `snap` won't have access to any files on its host OS which are not part of the snap package.

The solution to that problem is the [system-files interface](https://snapcraft.io/docs/system-files-interface) which is used by firefox.

See:

```
$ sudo snap connections firefox | grep system-files
system-files              firefox:etc-firefox             :system-files                    -
```

Which means that in order for `firefox` which was installed by `snap` to access any file (e.g: `policy.json` or `ca.crt`) it must be located under the `/etc/firefox` directory